# How to make sure the PC is having internet and then launch exec?

Tags: google-chrome, go, windows-8.1

I  have this application running, when system boots Windows 8.1 then it launch. But often the PC get into the network later as a result Google Chrome shows a failed page.

```
package main
import "os"
import "os/exec"
import "runtime"
import "encoding/json"

type Configuration struct {
  main []string
  name []string
  window []string
}

func main() {
  myos := runtime.GOOS;
  myarch := runtime.GOARCH;
  var chrome = "";
  var cmdopen *exec.Cmd;

  if myos == "windows" {
    if myarch == "386" {
      chrome = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";
    } else {      
      chrome = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";
    }          

    // Read config
    file, _ := os.Open("C:/Program Files (x86)/abc/package.json");
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file);
    configuration := Configuration{};
    err := decoder.Decode(&configuration);
    if err != nil {
      println("error: ", err);
    }

    println(configuration.main);

    // BUG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! But make sure local network or internet is available do not just execute the chrome like idiot, which is showing dead page
    cmdopen = exec.Command(chrome, "--app=http://icanhazip.com");
    err1 := cmdopen.Start();
    if err1 != nil {
      println("Failed: ", err1);
    } 

  } else {
    println("Incompatible");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do an `http.Get()`

```
func hazInternet() bool {
    res, err := http.Get("http://www.google.com/robots.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return false
    }
    res.Body.Close()
    return true
}
```

[Go PlayGround](http://play.golang.org/p/CEMvR_g-Wf)

Comment: What if the Windows 8.1 PC does not have DNS (like in enterprise they do not allow to go internet but only stay in local area network, how do you verify in that case if Ethernet or WiFi is online and it has at-least an IP)